# Hamachi alternatives or just the best option?

Tags: ssh, remote, vnc

Hamachi is a great way to connect behind a firewall when using Raspberry Pi, but it seems that we must pay to play now. What alternatives exist that work for a replacement? How could I set up my own version if I have access to a static IP server?

Comment: How about port forwarding and noip? That seems to be what a lot of people use.

Comment: I was just wanting to find something that I could make and control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you have on the static server you can use:

1. SSH port forwarding
2. Iptables port forwarding
3. Self-installed OpenVPN server

I'd also take a look into your internet router (ie cable modem) and check if port forwarding and DMZ options are available there. Configure your router to forward a specific port from home network or surface all ports from a specific home IP using DMZ (DMZ's security risk is higher as you expose more). Then configure "Dynamic DNS" in your router to automatically register roter's public IP in DNS using free services like dyndns.org, freedns.afraid.org or noip.com

Comment: For the router there's also the possibility to configure a DMZ, which forwards all unknown traffic to a specific device on the LAN.

Comment: Good point, Fred - added to the answer